# List / Repeater component for Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

In my previous project, I've used BeanItemContainer and a Table with GeneratedColumns to simply display a custom component that displays a search result, like google. Title, date, content in a vertical fashion. 
As horrible as it was (table) it worked.

Now I want to utilize Grid component for a new project, with the same objective.
The column will be generated and contain a custom component.

Will this work with Grid? is there something better, like a list or repeater component available? Any example of a single column with custom component?

It seems like Vaadin frowns on anything other than simple data or Button renderers.

**Update**

It looks like adding components don't work out of the box with [Grid 7.5+](https://vaadin.com/download/release/7.7/7.7.0/release-notes.html#knownissues)

Also, Grid cells like to be only be [fixed hight](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/11663590/11758770)

ComponentRederer [Add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/componentrenderer) support cell components, however fix height is still an issue.

**Sample code**:

```
 public class Result {
      String title;
      Date date;
      URL url;
      String description;
      List<String> tags;

      public Result (){}

 }

BeanItemContainer<Result> resultContainer = fetchResults(searchTerm);
```

I also use a Lazy Container too, beanitem used for simplicity.

I then have a RecordResultComponent that constructs the layout of a single record result in the follow layout:

```
 Title(link with Url)
 Date
 Description
 tag1 tag2 tag3 ...
```

Comment: Why use table/grid and not simply iterate through your item list, create an instance of your custom component for each item and add them in a [vertical layout](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-orderedlayout.html) (or maybe a [grid layout](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-gridlayout.html))?

Comment: I have a large amount of data and wanted to utilize the container-backed components.

Comment: its strange that table can render component and grid not out of the box. i guess you want to display also a lot of other columns and not only the component column. but if you dont need any table functionality like sorting, you could use a simple verticallayout.

Comment: You could also use [`FieldGroup` binding](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-itembinding.html) to some extent in order to achieve a similar effect, however it is difficult to imagine what exactly you're trying to do without seeing some code. Any chance you could share a [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: a lazy loading mechanism when the user scrolls (like table) would be great

Comment: @agassner, I've used table in the past, and that is what I will most likely have to use again. Just hoped there was a better alternative.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the situation but the [basic vaadin tutorial](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/tutorial.html) features displaying content like this in a grid, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Grid alongwith a [GeneratedPropertyContainer](https://vaadin.com/api/7.7.6/com/vaadin/data/util/GeneratedPropertyContainer.html).

Then, you can use a [HtmlRenderer](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html) on the custom column.

I hope it helps. :-)